# videojs javascript api breaks when setting options

Tags: javascript, html, api, video

I have the following javascript executes when the video tag has loaded via ajax, as suggested at the bottom of the following link https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/setup.md

```
<video id="video-1" style="max-width:90%; height:auto">
    <source src="/link/to/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

_V_("video-1", {controls:true}, function(){});
```

and this javascript basically breaks the controls and render it as text as below:

```
Play
Fullscreen
0:00
0:05
-0:05
Loaded: 0%
Progress: 0%
00:00
Mute
```

if I take out the options for controls as below and it works

```
_V_("video-1", {}, function(){});
```

I have the javascript library and css in the head element

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>
```

Comment: I start to suspect the javascript did not apply the css correctly...

Comment: The controls are clearly mis-formatted, but are they functional? Does clicking "Play" play the video?

Comment: yes, it's very likely it's not applying the css correctly, but I have `<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">` in head element already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I need to add the class into the video tag

```
<video id="video-1" class="vjs-default-skin">
```